# RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager and footer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, footer, android-gridlayout

I just coded a RecyclerView inside SwipeRefreshLayout and added a footer as a list item that prints the recyclerView to appear last.

The problem I have, is that the recyclerView can change its LayoutManager (LinearLayout or GridLayout). With the LinearLayout the footer is displayed correctly but when using the GridLayout the footer appears as another element and I would like it to appear below the grid.

Can someone tell me how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add some image for visual reference?